# What is Darwin’s impact on modern thought?

Tags: evolution, philosophy-of-biology

The question refers to a paper by Ernst Mayr, who was an eminent biologist on the field of the modern theory of evolution, Modern Synthesis. Mayr introduced and answered the title question in a short essay. It was published in the Proceedings of the American Philosophical Society from 1995, see [Darwin's impact on modern thought](https://www.jstor.org/stable/987231), and also later as [Darwin's influence](https://www-archiv.fdm.uni-hamburg.de/b-online/e36_2/darwin_influence.htm).

1. Mayr adresses six topics where in each case Darwins theory changed
   the Zeitgeist. I just list the keywords, for the details of the
   argumentation I refer to Mayr’s paper from 1995 (9 pages):

   - Against creationism: “Natural selection is the cause of order and    harmony in nature. There is no need to invoke divine design.”
   - Against  anthropocentrism: Man is not “something entirely different    from the rest of creation.” Hence it is not justified
     “to look at    everything from his specialized viewpoint.”
   - Against essentialism: The concept of *essences* with strict boundaries     between the corresponding classes is superseded by
     thinking in       *populations*, where every individual is different
     from each other       individual.
   - Against physicalism: Darwin “opposed the ideology of classical       physics, as it had developed […] under the influence of Newton.”
     According to Mayr  Darwin instead stresses “probabilism, the importance of emergence, population thinking, quality, and importance of observation and comparison”.
   - Against cosmic teleology: “The modern analysis of teleology has shown    that all evidence seemingly supporting cosmic teleology can
     be    explained quite readily by natural causes.”
   - Concerning free will: The Zeitgeist of Darwin’s time struggled with
     the question “How could anyone be responsible for his actions if
     they were dictated by his genetic makeup, his environment, by
     universal laws, or, worse by God?”
     Mayr ascribes to Darwin the
     viewpoint: “What we have, then, is a freedom of the will, a capacity
     of decision making which, however, is rather severly restricted by
     our biological constitutions, our upbringings, and prevailing
     circumstances.”
2. Assume a referee for a peer-review is comissioned by the editor of a
   philosophical journal: What could the referee mention as his/her summary
   concerning Mayr’s paper:

   - Importance of the subject,
   - originality of the paper,
   - quality of arguments,
   - possible objections,
   - and eventually making a recommendation of either acceptance, requesting changes, or rejecting the paper?

**Note**. This question results from an exchange of ideas on this platform with @Marco Ocram. On request I can email Mayr's original paper from 1994.

Comment: It's always odd to see someone framing evolution in terms of Darwin (usually it's creationists who do so, although Mayr is an evolutionary biologist). Yes, Darwin played a pivotal role in putting together the theory of evolution, but it was built on earlier work, and a whole lot of subsequent work supports it as well. It was accepted less because of Darwin's influence, and more because of the strength of the evidence supporting it. Not to understate Darwin's work and contribution, but it seems somewhat inevitable that humanity would come up with it eventually.

Comment: @NotThatGuy The superiority of Darwin's theory is that it explains how species emerge and has much empirical evidence to back it up. But many people considered various versions of evolutionary theory before Darwin, notably his grandfather (Erasmus Darwin). I think the inevitability, as you put it, of Darwin's theory can be said to be a great counterexample to Newton's insistence on non positing hypotheses in empirical science. Newton was, strictly speaking, talking about *experimental philosophy*, but some philosophers of science extend his results to other fields.

Comment: If someone hadn't speculated, before Darwin, about evolution, even without much empirical evidence (which is very unprobable, exactly because such theory is inevitable), it's hard to imagine anyone coming up with such an explanation. Yet some historians of science who focus only on experimental sciences, like physics, forget about that when criticizing (like ex. Feyerabend does, albeit, I believe, for slightly different reasons) Galileo's, Kepler's etc. cosmological speculations (to show that the great scientists weren't so scientific afterall). I see such speculations as nevertheless

Comment: constituting a contribution to human thought, though at the same time it's unthinkable that many bold conjectures which we now recognize as constituting a part of mature scientific theories didn't exist.

Comment: One thing that stands out to me is "physicalism". Mayr states that it was "dominant in 1859". But  physicalism in the modern sense did not even come up until mid-20th century. He later explains that he means "ideology of classical physics", but a) that is not what "physicalism" means today, and b) he is wrong about 1859 too, vitalism was quite popular at the time, even among physicists, see [hsm](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/17273/55). If anything, "Darwin's thought" (whatever his personal judgment on it was) aided the rise of modern physicalism by promoting reduction to physical causes.

Comment: @NotThatGuy humanity would come up with it eventually, and then it would be named after whoever had been prominent in that process. We like our heroes and villains. Imagine a musical group where we didn't know the names of the people? Might as well be AI at that point.

Comment: There is always a "father of..." as being the person in the right place at the right time to get the recognition. But ideas don't pop out of a vacuum: they are themselves an evolution. I read somewhere that Einstein did a deal with his wife: you'll get the money and I'll get the glory.

Comment: **Mathematical Challenges To Darwin’s Theory Of Evolution**
https://www.hoover.org/research/mathematical-challenges-darwins-theory-evolution-david-berlinski-stephen-meyer-and-david > "Darwin’s main problem, molecular biology, to which Meyer explains,
> comparing it to digital world, that building a new biological function
> is similar to building a new code, which Darwin could not understand
> in his era. The cell represents very complex machinery, with
> complexities increasing over time, which is difficult to explain by a
> theory. Meyer further explains how difficult it is to know what a
>

Comment: I have voted to close. Five questions for each of six topics is 29 questions too many for a SE question. I think many of the 30 would be interesting if posed separately.

Comment: Jo, here's something of interest to your question: https://www.geneseo.edu/~everett/Darwintalk.htm#:~:text=In%20the%20philosophy%20of%20religion,called%20design%20or%20teleological%20argument.

Comment: @TKol I read Everett's paper now. In comparison to Mayr he makes some proposals concerning lessons learned from the theory of evolution and putting them into praxis. While Mayr seems rather fundamental how to think with the new philosophical concepts. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It has to have been pretty huge. According to the [2020 Philpapers survey](https://survey2020.philpeople.org/survey/results/all), over 66% of philosophers are atheists - the vast majority of those atheists believe evolution is the driver for diversity of life on earth, and that Humans are the product of evolution from other previously existing species.

I'd be willing to bet that the percent of philosophers identifying as atheists shot up drastically as Evolution gained popularity among scientists.

Understanding humans as evolved creatures would also have been a source for many new papers and ideas on ethics and morality, social behavior, psychology, and probably politics, to name just a few affected topics within Philosophy. Understanding humans as evolved creatures could also have a profound impact on how philosophers view the relationship between humans and other life on Earth, including potentially moral responsibilities to those other creatures.

Answer (score -2):

Darwinism is similar to Newtonian physics. Seems correct on the surface but breaks down under the electron microscope. The influence of Darwinism is not about right or wrong, God or nature. It is about philosophical views: nature is real vs nature is artificial.

Comment: How is that anything beyond your own personal opinion, please?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking - The philosophical views of the World that is not God's creation, neither a natural phenomenon, are hard to source from academia-accepted publications. If this is an artificial creation, then both Darwin and theology are correct. You can program a new religion and a new law of physics on the same day.

Comment: To my knowledge, 99.9% of scientists would disagree that the theory of evolution "breaks down under the electron microscope". The theory of evolution accurately models and predicts what we see - how do you define being "about right or wrong", if it excludes that? Also, what does "nature is real" and "nature is artificial" mean? Even theists who reject evolution tend to accept that nature is "real". If you mean "artificial" in the sense of "made by God", then evolution is just one of many fields where we found evidence against some explanation that God did it, but many theists accept evolution.

Comment: @NotThatGuy - "To my knowledge, 99.9% of scientists" - I think you are trying to put it as black and white. Deny Theory of Evolution, or support it. I can say that a lot of biologists don't deny obvious mechanisms described by Darwin but accept some serious mathematical problems when trying to model random mutations as a sole engine of evolution.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance I expect there are roughly zero reputable biologists who'll say random mutations are the "sole engine of evolution" (though it depends on how you define "engine"). The mathematical problems people run into when trying to model evolution are usually creationists who do indeed try to model evolution as pure randomness, which disregards the other half of the theory of evolution: natural selection. And they ignore that different mutations occur in parallel across a population, that some mutations are more likely than others, that abiogenesis is distinct from evolution.

Comment: @NotThatGuy - I don't share your confidence. On a molecular level, biologists are not even close to being able to model the beginning of life, even less its complex progression. The most fundamental question about life: what drives these molecules together in a humongously complex way - is not answered.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance The beginning of life is abiogenesis, which is distinct from evolution. The evolution of life across billions of years is very well-supported by evidence, regardless of what happened before that, regardless of how that started (although we certainly have some evidence supporting the origination of life). Depending on what you mean by "what drives these molecules together", either the answer is "natural selection", or evolution doesn't try to model that, similar to how a model of traffic doesn't model how car engines work - that wouldn't be a problem with evolution.

Comment: @NotThatGuy -  "or evolution doesn't try to model that" - don't you think that if you decide not to scrutinize Darwin's theory under an electron microscope and accept it as is without proving that a reasonable number of random mutations could produce viable new proteins, you would be inline with people who used to watch stars with a naked eye for thousands of years?

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance [Here's](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9214755/) [some](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrg2808) [research](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4448608/) on protein evolution, found with 2 seconds of Googling. Why are you acting as if no-one asks a question that's been actively researched? But scientists are more concerned with trying to understand how and why things happen, rather than indulging creationism pseudoscience. Also, side note: watching stars with the naked eye produced a ton of knowledge about movement of astronomical bodies.

Answer (score -3):

From a *biased*'(unfortunately) sample of www content, I'd say *atheism* and Nietzsche (übermenschen) and the so called *Darwinian revolution* (the world doesn't revolve around "man") and of course, the *delusion* that all of the above follows from *The Theory of Evolution*. Having fun?